# Is Windows "metric" MKSA or CGS

Tags: regional-settings

When you visit Control Panel => Region => Additional Settings => Numbers, you have the option to set "Measurement System:" to either "U.S." or "Metric" . Which of these SI (I am assuming metric means SI, if another standard is meant documentation on this would be appreciated) is this referring to?

I know this sets the "IsMetric" flag in .NET programs, documented here,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx

What I don't know is where in Windows itself this flag is actually used, and how.

Comment: You That would be on the region you indicate you are in.  IsMetric doesn’t set anything, it gets the value of that setting, a different property would have to set it which doesn’t exist.  The IsMetric property is a read only property.

Comment: I have no idea what MKSA or CGM stands for

Comment: That should have been CGS. They're Meters, Kilograms, Seconds, Amperes, as opposed to Centimeters, Grams, Seconds.

In any event I would like to give you credit for your answer, if this is just a flag and powers of 10 are an application developer's responsibility this answers my question.